# Get average of all the table's average - Qlikview

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, set-analysis

Is it possible to get the average value of each straight table and get the average again?

Example: Avg(1.99%+3.66%+3.49%+2.26%+2.14%+2.61%+5.54%+3.11%+2.92%+1.06%)

[image]

Comment: not directly from the tables. The total avg should be driven from the data. It will be useful to post example of how your data looks and how some of the table averages are caluculated

Comment: I couldn't come up with the right formula as each table is set by dimension, and this dimension i.e. Week, can be multiple weeks if set on filters. I tried using aggregate but this is only possible for single selected or 1 week. Each table has expression i.e. `Sum({$<[A]={$(=vVariable1)}, [Group]={'TableA'}>} [Duration])/Sum({$<[A]={'*'}, [Group]={'TableA'}>} [Duration])`

Comment: possible to upload the qvw somewhere (with subset or scrambled data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the complexity of your table expressions, but the general Idea is to "simulate" your straight/pivot table totals via an `aggr` functions:

for example, for Table where the dimension is `Week` and the expressions is "sum(val)", you could do something like this in a variable:

```
avg(aggr( sum(val), Week))
```

if you have multiple dimensions in a Table, then just add them to the `aggr` fragmentation (ie: `avg(aggr( sum(val), Week,Group))`)

then run all these calc/variables in `rangeAvg`
In your case you could do something like:

```
    rangeAvg(
    aggr(Sum({$<[A]={$(=vVariable1)}, [Group]={'TableA'}>} [Duration])/Sum({$<[A]={'*'}, [Group]={'TableA'}>} [Duration]),Week),
    aggr(Sum({$<[A]={$(=vVariable1)}, [Group]={'TableA'}>} [Duration])/Sum({$<[A]={'*'}, [Group]={'TableA'}>} [Duration]),MonthYear),
    aggr(Sum({$<[A]={$(=vVariable1)}, [Group]={'TableA'}>} [Duration])/Sum({$<[A]={'*'}, [Group]={'TableA'}>} [Duration]),Year)
)
```

side note: I wont get into vb macro as it is only relevant to qlikview and cannot be used in qliksense, but in general it is possible to access cell values via vb

Comment: I've tried doing the aggregate but this only works for 1 variable of dimension. I have a filter where you can select many weeks. Each table can be many weeks not just 1 week. If I select only 1 week, i.e. 201701 (means 1st week of the year), it can show the average from all the tables, but if many weeks are selected, it only shows '-' or blank.

Comment: If you want to all week always then just add to your set analysis 'Week=' - this will always ignore current week selections.
if you want ALWAYS avg on ALL data then use 'sum({1<[A]={$(=vVariable1)}....'

Comment: Hi, I've already solved it. I did not put Avg before the Aggr when I should have. Thank you for your help.